# What to install when working with PHP offline?

Tags: php

I'm actually new here at stackoverflow. I'm currently preparing for my thesis next year and planning to use php for my program. Can I ask what software/s do I need to install to work with PHP offline? Please I need a step by step process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Are these available online? What other software do I need to install in my laptop?

Comment: Install a web server like XAMPP or WAMPP on your local machine. Don't forget your favorite text editor. :) Just search `XAMPP` on google. Cheers kababayan!

Comment: PHP can actually be used as a local webserver itself if you run it from the command line with the `-S` option. So at the bare minimum you just need to install PHP. If you wanted extra stuff that xampp or others provide, like MySQL, then those can easily be installed separately.

Comment: @ArnNhel Those are available online and that's all you need to start.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **wamp** server or **xamp** server to test php locally. [You can download wamp server from here](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

All you have to do is put your **php** code inside the `wamp/www` directory and call the corresponding file from the browser as `localhost/yourScrpt.php`

In this cases, following the instructions of the distributor will show you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you use windows system wamp(code will be in c:\wamp\www) or xmpp(code will be in c:\xmpp\htdocs) is better. If you go with linux you can find tutorials "how to install lamp ubuntu" and your php code will reside at /var/www/html. and best luck....

Answer (score 2):

You need XAMPP installed(https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) on your machine. There are a number of tutorials available online to get you started with your first PHP application. Here's a link to the guide I usually link people to https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/.

The other thing you need is a good editor. I keep switching between Atom and Sublime text as I feel they are the best editors available at the moment. Also, installing [these](http://neverstopbuilding.com/sublime-plugins-for-php) plugins for sublime text will make your coding experience much more pleasant.

Hope this helps and good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenServer. It's not a only WAMP, contained more portable programs for web developer. The site is in russian but programm have english interface. See here: http://open-server.ru/download/

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to run PHP code on your computer. The easiest way to run the PHP code is by installing the software such as XAMPP and WAMP. These software creates local web server for testing purposes. XAMPP stands for Cross-Platform (X), Apache (A), MySQL (M), PHP (P) and Perl (P). WAMP stands for Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP. For WAMP http://www.wampserver.com/en/ and for XAMPP https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above XAMPP, WAMP, MAMP (OSX) are all good options. Especially since they're on the easier side to setup and require little linux knowledge. For serous local development I use a vagrant VM with an image of ubuntu. While this may be more advanced it can be very useful (especially in teams) when working with complex server environments.

[Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)

Heres a tool for building bootstrapped Vagrant ISO's [Puphpet](https://puphpet.com/#vagrantfile-local).